# Get the Location of Right Click Event on Context Menu Action

Tags: macos, cocoa, contextmenu, nsmenu

My custom `NSView` subclass overrides `menu(for:)` in order to display a context menu on right click (ctrl-click).

I created a menu item with appropriate target/action, and added it to the menu.

I want to instantiate a subview and place it at the location in which the right click originally occurred; However, it isn't clear how to obtain the location of the original click event that causes the menu to be displayed.

The `sender` argument of the action method gets the NSMenuItem instance, but this does not seem to have any property to determine its position on screen (or its superview).

**How can I determine the location of the initial right click event?**

Comment: You have to store (the location of) the original event somewhere. You can use the `representedObject` of the menu item.

Comment: How? Right-click does not trigger `mouseDown(with:)`.

Comment: Ohh, you mean, store the location of the event passed in in `menu(for:)`?

Comment: Thank you, it works. I didn't think I could get the click location from the `NSEvent` instance passed to `menu(for:)` (I guess that's one of the things it's passed for). If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store (the location of) the event passed to `menu(for:)` somewhere. You can use the representedObject of the menu item.